# How to free up RAM when using Juypter Notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Juypter Notebook where I am working with large matrices (`20000x20000`). I am running multiple iterations, but I am getting an error saying that I do not have enough RAM after every iteration. If I restart the kernel, I can run the next iteration, **so perhaps the Juypter Notebook is running out of RAM because it stores the variables** (which aren't needed for the next iteration). Is there a way to free up RAM?

Edit: I don't know if the bold segment is correct. In any case, I am looking to free up RAM, any suggestions are welcome.

```
## Outputs:
two_moons_n_of_samples = [int(_) for _ in np.repeat(20000, 10)]
```

```
for i in range(len(two_moons_n_of_samples)):
    # print(f'n: {two_moons_n_of_samples[i]}')

    ## Generate the data and the graph
    X, ground_truth, fid = synthetic_data({'type': 'two_moons', 'n': two_moons_n_of_samples[i], 'fidelity': 60, 'sigma': 0.18})
    N = X.shape[0]
    dist_mat = sqdist(X.T, X.T)
    opt = {
        'graph': 'full',
        'tau': 0.004,
        'type': 's'
        }
    LS = dense_laplacian(dist_mat, opt)

    ## Eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    tic = time.time() ## Time how long to calculate eigenvalues/eigenvectors
    V, E = np.linalg.eigh(LS)
    idx = np.argsort(V)
    V, E = V[idx], E[:, idx]
    V = V / V.max()
    decomposition_time = time.time() - tic

    ## Initialize u0
    u0 = np.zeros(N)
    for j in range(len(fid[0])):
        u0[fid[0][j]] = 1
    for j in range(len(fid[1])):
        u0[fid[1][j]] = -1

    ## Initialize parameters
    dt = 0.05
    gamma = 0.07
    max_iter = 100

    ## Run MAP estimation
    tic = time.time()
    u_eg, _ = probit_optimization_eig(E, V, u0, dt, gamma, fid, max_iter)
    eg_time = time.time() - tic

    ## Run MAP estimation with CG
    tic2 = time.time()
    u_cg, _ = probit_optimization_cg(LS, u0, dt, gamma, fid, max_iter)
    cg_time = time.time() - tic2

    ## Write to file:
    with open('results2_two_moons_egvscg.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{i},{two_moons_n_of_samples[i]},{decomposition_time + eg_time},{cg_time}\n')
```

Error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.07 GiB for an array with shape (12000, 12000) and data type float64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\2/ipykernel_2344/941022539.py in <module>
     11         'type': 's'
     12         }
---> 13     LS = dense_laplacian(dist_mat, opt)
     14 
     15     ## Eigenvalues and eigenvectors

C:/Users/\util\graph\dense_laplacian.py in dense_laplacian(dist_mat, opt)
     69         D_inv_sqrt = 1.0 / np.sqrt(D)
     70         D_inv_sqrt = np.diag(D_inv_sqrt)
---> 71         L = np.eye(W.shape[0]) - D_inv_sqrt @ W @ D_inv_sqrt
     72         # L = 0.5 * (L + L.T)
     73     if opt['type'] == 'rw':

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.07 GiB for an array with shape (12000, 12000) and data type float64
```

[image]

Comment: Or rewrite the code so it doesn't waste memory? 4M items is *not* that large. How much RAM does each element use? Even with 128bits, that's 64MB. If each iteration allocates a new copy of the matrix though, eg to hold the results, you'll soon run out of RAM. You'll also waste time allocating a new 64MB buffer each time. The solution to that is to reuse temporary buffers instead of allocating new ones

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, it's 40M items. And I am not sure how I would rewrite the code or check how much RAM each element uses. Each iteration writes a single value to a text file and I don't need anything else from that iteration.

Comment: Are you using Numpy? i guess it automatically handles such stuff

Comment: @user13966865 Yes I am.

Comment: It's 400M but the error says that a new 1GB array of 12K*12K 64-bit floats can't be allocated. That's a *different* array. Again, reuse buffers instead of allocating new ones. And post the code and error as *text*, not images. It looks like the error occurs when you try to *load* data, but I can't go back and forth between the image and the comment box. *Post the code and error as text*!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just experimenting with sizes. `11000x11000` is fine, but at `12000x12000` it runs out of RAM after a single iteration. I do not know how to reuse buffers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have posted the code.

Comment: Assuming D is the original matrix, this code is allocating 1GB on each line. It's not just that Python can run out of RAM. Memory can become so fragmented there's no single 1 GB block left to allocate a new buffer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well what is the solution? A single iteration runs fine, so I am thinking that it is possible to just free up that RAM before each iteration.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem, the way I solved it was -

1. Writing Functions wherever preprocessing is required and returning only preprocessed variables.
2. Deleting used huge variables just use `del x`
3. Clearing Garbage

```py
import gc 
gc.collect()
```

4. Sometimes clearing garbage doesn't helps and i used to clear the cache as well by using

```py
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6") # clearing cache 
libc.malloc_trim(0)
```

5. I tried to batch my code as far as possible.

I think the best solution for you would be to **batch** the matrix multiplication. Libraries like TensorFlow and PyTorch does it by default, not sure about NumPy though. Check - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul ( An API for matrix multiplication in batches ). Most of modern-day GPU calculations are possible due to batching !

Comment: Deleting and garbage collecting are expensive operations though, especially when dealing with GB-sized buffers. The way such problems are handled allocating large-enough buffers from the start and reusing them, or simply not loading everything in RAM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but ML workloads load entire dataframes more than 2-3 GBs ( sometimes more than 29 GB) what should be done in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding more swap space which is really easy and will probably save you more time and headache than redesigning the code to be less wasteful or trying to delete and garbage collect unnecessary objects. It would of course be slower than using ram memory since it will use the disk to simulate the extra memory needed.
Excellent answer on how to do this on ubuntu, [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/178726/328467)